# Ansible: get list of hosts in comma separated value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following loop in a template:

```
{% for host in groups['dbnodes'] %}
 {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

the issue is that it gives the output in list of ip's and I need it in comma separated value. Any idea how to achieve that?

the answer I get look like this:

```
10.0.0.190
10.0.0.117
10.0.0.151
```

but I need it like this:

```
10.0.0.190,10.0.0.117,10.0.0.151
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix to your Jinja2 template:

```
{% for host in groups['dbnodes'] -%}
 {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: The result what I get from here it's wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm:// 1,0,.,0,.,0,.,1,9,0
 1,.,0,.,0,.,1,1,7
 1,0,.,0,.,0.,1,5,1 not exactly what I need

Comment: In the loop this is what I get: `10.0.0.190
 10.0.0.117
 10.0.0.151`

Comment: @zozo6015 I added a fix to your template. It still can be done with list filters and maps, but this is cleaner, imho.

Comment: @techraf do you know how can I get the same result using plain Ansible with yaml fie?